# How to empty DBM file in Python efficiently?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dbm

There is a command in DBM module to delete the value stored at a key.

```
del d[key]      # delete data stored at key (raises KeyError   # if no such key)
```

But I cannot even iterate with this command, because the Runtime error occurs.(RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration.)

```
import dbm
db=dbm.open("file.db","c")
for key in db:
    del db[key]
print(len(db))
db.close()
```

Is there an efficient way to empty DMB file at once?
I am using Python 3.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for key in list(db):
    del db[key]
```

should work.

**EDIT:** If the goal is just to empty the database completely, you can also close the database and re-open it with `dbm.open('filename', 'n')`.  The `'n'` flag means "Always create a new, empty database, open for reading and writing"; it seems to override any previously-existing file.

Comment: Thank you it works! Are there any solutions without iteration? Deleting files with OS.REMOVE is also an option, but DMB created 2 files. Aren't there a smart way like a DBM.CLEAR() or something?

Comment: I have tried it with "n" flag, but it does not override the file.      >>> db=dbm.open("db","c")        
>>> db["line"]=("somedata")       
>>> db.close()        
>>> db=dbm.open("db","n")      
>>> data=db["line"]       
>>> print(data)         
b'somedata'      
>>> db.close()

Comment: Strange, it does for me (Python 2.7.3 on 32-bit Linux).

Comment: Maybe it is a Python version problem. I am using Python 3.3.2 32-bit on Windows7. If flag "n" does not override the file, there is no need for it, because a new file can be created with "c" flag.

Comment: Ah, found it.  It's really buried in the docs :-(  On Windows, it will use this: http://docs.python.org/3/library/dbm.html#module-dbm.dumb which documents its flag as ignored.  I'd still file a bug report if I were you, saying that either the docs at http://docs.python.org/3/library/dbm.html#dbm.open should include a warning, or dumbdbm should be fixed.